# Assigning keys to an empty array

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is what I currently have with my code:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$offices = [];
if (count($wp_query->posts) > 0) {
    $offices = $wp_query->posts;
}

foreach ($offices as $office) {

    /* Set the $office variable to return all office names */
    $office = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id');
}
```

I have my $offices = [] .. empty array that returns the following:

```
 Array (
     [0] => WP_Post Object
         (
             [ID] => 52856
```

then I have my $office variable in the foreach that returns the get_post_meta for _office_id that returns the following:

```
 Array (
     [0] => RIODEJANFHBRZ )
```

How could I build an array out of the $office varible and put the office value as assigned array key so it's `[_office_id] =>` etc..? Tried all sorts of ways and was unable too.

Example:

```
Array (
     [_office_id] => RIODEJANFHBRZ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add true in the last param of the function. Adding true will give you a single result and not an array.

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
  $key['_office_id'] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);
  print_r2($key);
}
```

Refer to the this URL:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm, can't believe I overlooked that - Thanks @muzaffar.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it somewhat figured out but I don't think it's 100% right just yet.

Here is my result:

```
Array (
    [_office_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => RIODEJANFHBRZ
        )

)
```

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $key['_office_id'] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id');
    print_r2($key);
}
```

Isn't it supposed to be:

> [_office_id] => RIODEJANFHBRZ